# How to pass a dynamic id from array to property inside component - React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm working on mini project named smart-house. I have a form that generate room with `color,name and type` .
My problem is that I cant find a way to inset to property `index` in `<SingleRoom />` component dynamic id that match to the room that I clicked on.

My App.js: 
For now the property `index={0}` because I don't know how to set there the current id.

```
class App extends Component {
  state ={
    rooms:[]
  }

  addRoom = (id,type,name,color) =>{
    this.setState({rooms:[{id:id,type:type, name:name, color:color, devices:[]}, ...this.state.rooms]});
  }

  render(){
    return (
    <div className="App">
      <Title title="Smart House" />
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={() => {return <HomePage rooms={this.state.rooms.map((item,i) => {
            return <Link to={`/room/${item.name}`}><ArchiveRoom color={item.color} name={item.name} index={i} /></Link>
            })} />}} />
          <Route path="/addroom" component={() => {return <AddRoom add={this.addRoom} />}} />
          <Route path={`/room/:id`} component={() => { 
            return <SingleRoom room={this.state.rooms} index={0} /> 
          }} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

my SingleRoom.js component

```
export default class SingleRoom extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            index: props.index,
            name: this.props.name,
            type: this.props.type
        }
    }

    getIndex = () =>{
        this.props.index(this.state.index)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="single-room">
                <Link to="/"><div className="add-room homepage-button"><button>⬅</button></div></Link> 
                     <h4>Room name: {this.props.room[this.state.index].name}</h4>
                     <h4>Room type: {this.props.room[this.state.index].type}</h4>   
                <button className="add-room-button">Add Device</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

ArchiveRoom.js component:

```
export default class ArchiveRoom extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            index: props.index
        }
    }

    getIndex = () => {
        this.props.index(this.state.index);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.props.singleRoom} style={{backgroundColor:this.props.color, cursor:"pointer"}} className="archive-room">
                <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Thanks very much to helpers :]

Comment: See [redux](https://react-redux.js.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Route path={`/room/:id`} component={props => { 
            return <SingleRoom room={this.state.rooms} {...props} /> 
          }} />
```

You can access id as `this.props.match.params.id` in `SingleRoom` component